# select random image from two different arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, arc4random

I need to send an image to UIImageView randomly from two different arrays. I am not sure how do i proceed with this?

```
var imgSetOne: [String] = ["car1.png", "car2.png", "car3.png", "car4.png", "car5.png"]
let imgOneRandom = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))

var imgSetTwo: [String] = ["bus1.png", "bus2.png", "bus3.png", "bus4.png", "bus5.png"]
let imgTwoRandom = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))

UIImage(named: imgSetOne[imgOneRandom]) OR UIImage(named: imgSetTwo[imgTwoRandom])
```

I am trying to select random image from first array and second array using arc4random_uniform. Now i want to display image either from first array result or second array result to the UIImageView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your arrays have the same size, then you can just select array to pick image randomly:

```
let arrayIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
UIImage(named: arrayIndex == 0 ? imgSetOne[imgOneRandom] : imgSetTwo[imgTwoRandom])
```

Note that if arrays have different size and you still want to choose each image from both arrays with same probability you will need to tweak this logic a little (will leave it as a homework excersize)

Comment: Thanks! It worked for different array size as well. To get the same probability i suppose we should use only one random integer unlike I used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Vladimir answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39105727/2463616) you can create operator for this:

```
func ||(left: String, right: String) -> String {
    let isRight = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
    return isRight == 1 ? right : left
}
```

And use like this:

```
UIImage(named: "left" || "right")
```

Comment: No. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

[Vladimir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39105727/3141234) does exactly what you need. In case you need to pick more than 2, you can do this:

```
let imgSetOne = ["car1.png", "car2.png", "car3.png", "car4.png", "car5.png"]
let imgOneRandom = imgSetOne[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt(imgSetOne.count)))]

let imgSetTwo = ["bus1.png", "bus2.png", "bus3.png", "bus4.png", "bus5.png"]
let imgTwoRandom = imgSetTwo[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt(imgSetTwo.count)))]

let candidates = [imgOneRandom, imgTwoRandom]
let finalPick = candidates[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt(candidates.count)))]
UIImage(named: finalPick)
```

Comment: arc4random_uniform accepting only unsigned int. So I used  'let imgOneRandom = imgSetOne[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt(imgSetOne.count)))]'  Thanks !!